# Font-size handler JS

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the fonts as we have on Word.

[image]

and I were wondering if already exist any library that does that, I did not found anything yet, but probably my words on search is not very good.

I am using a simple code as bellow from increasing and decreasing, but I will need something more like:

[image]

where we have on small fonts, smaller differences and on bigger fonts bigger differences.

```js
     $(".increaseFont").on("click", function () {
                var $font = $("#myfont");
                var currentFontSize = parseInt($font.css('fontSize'));
                var targetFont = currentFontSize + 1;

                if (targetFont <= 24) {
                    $font.css("fontSize", targetFont + "px");
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfont"> Hello, I am trying to do some JS </div>

<div class="increaseFont"> Click me </div>
```

What do you suggest me?

**UPDATE:**
I am not using a WYSIWYG HTML Editor or something similar, because I am creating my own board and there is no room for markup editor there. So what I am doing is when the user hovers the board he/she can edit the font size with two buttons.

Comment: Any WYSIWYG editor. Like CKEditor/summernote/etc

Comment: AFAIK you can easily just hardcode an array for that, e.g. `[5, 5.5, 6.5, ...]`, and then when incrementing/decrementing font sizes, simply get the index of the current font size in the array and pick the next/previous item in the array.

Comment: Set your font sizes using `rem` units and just change the base size on `body` if you want them all to relatively size up and down https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/

Comment: Justinas, I use some editors markup in another place, but this one is a board, that I developed, and I do it inside the board.

Comment: Terry, yes, I think that is the easiest and better way for now. I am going to stick with the array idea.

Comment: Dominic, Yes I should be using rem on it, it would also help in different screen sizes. Than you, I will keep with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try like this:

```js
$(".font-sizes").change(function () {
    var size = $(".font-sizes").val();
    console.log(size);
    $("#myfont").css({fontSize: size + "px"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfont"> Hello, I am trying to do some JS </div>

<select class="font-sizes">
  <option>--select font size--</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hey Vasu, that is an awesome idea, it is similar to the array idea. btw I didn't know that I could do like that `$("#myfont").css({fontSize: size + "px"});`, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way of doing, it is to follow as  Vasu and Terry logic. 
See the following.

Thank you a lot, guys.

```js
$(".increaseFont").on("click", function () {
     var $font = $("#myfont");
     var fontSizeOptions = [5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 30];
     var currentFontSize = parseInt($font.css('fontSize'));
     var currentIndex = fontSizeOptions.indexOf(currentFontSize);
     var targetFont = fontSizeOptions[currentIndex + 1];
 
 
     $font.css("fontSize", targetFont + "px");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myfont" style="font-size: 5px;"> Hello, I am trying to do some JS </div>

<div class="increaseFont"> Click me </div>
```

P.S.: the code still needs to prevent some failures.